# How to implement Ajax call in Datatables server side processing

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I have a 20,0000+ data in sever side I have to plot in datatable based on their gender.
I have three categories

1. All-show all data in list
2. women+kids data list
3. men data list

First time load Its all fine by choosing radio button ,In some cases I got all previous data list but the count still shows

[image]

Code :

```
function load_data(preferredGender) {
   $("#user_table").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "dataType": "json",
        "deferRender": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/list_customers",
            "data": {
                preferredGender
            },
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "row"
            },
            {
                "data": "email"
            },

        ],
    });
}
```

Comment: try this. Has a demo as well. https://ashishontech.xyz/server-side-pagination-jquery-datatable/

Comment: Thanks I have fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all Thanks for your valuable time.I have fixed the issue

**Issue in Sending request to get data on each click and the responding time and data.**

on before send in ajax call aborting if  any previous request exits and aborting

```
beforeSend:function(){
if (userTable && userTable.hasOwnProperty('settings')) {
     userTable.settings()[0].jqXHR.abort();
    }
}
```

If you have any alternative for this please suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table-id').DataTable({    
"processing": true, 
"serverSide": true, 
"ajax": {
    "url": "URL",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function ( data ) {
            data.gender = $('#gender').val();

        },
    "dataSrc": function ( json ) {             
       return json.data;
   }
},
"columnDefs": [
{ 
    "targets": [ ], 
    "orderable": false, 
},
],
"fnDrawCallback": function() {          

 },
});
```

Comment: I have doubt by returning Json .data on dataSrc can we neglect columns?